# Netbeans 8.2 menu text size

Tags: netbeans

For some reason Netbeans 8.2 is showing the tiniest menus ever on my laptop and I can't do much to make it bigger.

I've tried to modify `netbeans.conf` with not much success.

The only thing that worked has been launching NetBeans through command prompt with the following code:

```
netbeans --fontsize 20
```

But I need it to stay that way, do not want to be using commands everytime I launch the IDE.

I've found many solutions but for older versions of Netbeans.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have the same effect as adding the parameter of `--fontsize 20` as
command parameter, you may put it in the file 
[netbeans.conf](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqNetbeansConf)
(link to Netbeans Wiki).

On Windows, this file is typically found in `C:\Program Files\Netbeans\etc\netbeans.conf`.

The parameter that will have the same effect as being on the command is:

> **netbeans_default_options**
>
> Any parameters passed to the JVM or NetBeans during start-up, such as
>   memory configuration parameters, debugging options,
>   [--fontsize](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqFontSize)
>   Look > and Feel switches, various experimental switches, etc..

You need to append `--fontsize 20` to `netbeans_default_options`.